# Create Installers for Add-ins using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, add-in

I need help building a customized Installer using visual studio 2008
to install Office 2007 (add-in) tool bars that I have made.

How can I create installers for Add-ins I've made?

Comment: Ziv: Please don't ask for people to contact you directly; this site uses a Q & A format, so that the 'answer' is here for everyone to take part in.

Answer (score 2):

There's a 2-part series on MSDN outlining this in detail:

Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer [(Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx) and [(Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc616991.aspx)